# DigestValue of the xml document in php

Tags: php, xml, sha256

Could anyone please help me how to accomplish the correct DigestValue in the XML document? I have some XML examples from the creator, but somehow I cannot generate the same SHA256 hash in PHP.

The documentation says that the <soap:Body> should be hashed using SHA256 algorithm. Well, from what I understand I need to

1. canonicalize the xml (c14n)
2. create a SHA256 hash from it
3. base64 encode it

The hash result from this example should be obviously
TWpSLQpOXSUe8k6Q8lAd7DyMhWkTIcbHNifrPnWDG/M=

How to accomplish it in php from the code below?

I tried this:

```
$xml='<soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-AB79979F3364F5119A14761286403964"><Trzba xmlns="http://fs.mfcr.cz/eet/schema/v3"><Hlavicka dat_odesl="2016-09-19T19:06:37+02:00" prvni_zaslani="false" uuid_zpravy="ab1bc7a0-5ab0-4d61-a170-2982f2d83784"/><Data celk_trzba="34113.00" cerp_zuct="679.00" cest_sluz="5460.00" dan1="-172.39" dan2="-530.73" dan3="975.65" dat_trzby="2016-08-05T00:30:12+02:00" dic_popl="CZ1212121218" id_pokl="/5546/RO24" id_provoz="273" porad_cis="0/6460/ZQ42" pouzit_zboz1="784.00" pouzit_zboz2="967.00" pouzit_zboz3="189.00" rezim="0" urceno_cerp_zuct="324.00" zakl_dan1="-820.92" zakl_dan2="-3538.20" zakl_dan3="9756.46" zakl_nepodl_dph="3036.00"/><KontrolniKody><pkp cipher="RSA2048" digest="SHA256" encoding="base64">JvCv0lXfT74zuviJaHeO91guUfum1MKhq0NNPxW0YlBGvIIt+I4QxEC3QP6BRwEkIS14n2WN+9oQ8nhQPYwZX7L4W9Ie7CYv1ojcl/YiF4560EdB3IpRNRj3UjQlwSZ5ucSM9vWqp0UTbhJDSUk5/WjC/CEiSYv7OQIqa0NJ0f0+ldzGveLRSF34eu2iqAhs/yfDnENlnMDPVB5ko/zQO0vcC93k5DEWEoytTIAsKd6jKSO7eama8Qe+d0wq9vBzudkfLgCe2C1iERJuyHknhjo9KOx10h5wk99QqVGX8tthpAmryDcX2N0ZGkzJHuzzebnYsxXFYI2tKOJLiLLoLQ==</pkp><bkp digest="SHA1" encoding="base16">3F9119C1-FBF34535-D30B60F8-9859E4A6-C8C8AAFA</bkp></KontrolniKody></Trzba></soap:Body>';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$doc->loadXML($xml);
echo base64_encode(hash('SHA256',$doc->C14N(true),true));
```

But this is returning me other hash value :-( Maybe I am just taking the wrong part of the XML source. Any ideas from what part of text/how did they count the hash and how to have the same result in php? The whole working example (taken from [http://www.etrzby.cz/assets/cs/prilohy/CZ1212121218.valid.v3.1.xml) is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-A79845F15C5549CA0514761283545351">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-A79845F15C5549CA0514761283545705"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-A79845F15C5549CA0514761283545594"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>M8/dBI/LLuwxP8ZoeRKVVpzIhQhyUDI0l6bglhNWKC0=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>DlFiF51sdtc0zeqgCsuSY6EU5emX7Hka6Ox3gviR4dpqyrwj6O8cm4oWkUTl+erINf9CpOG2y1z5y83+DubuGmiOPsACeEZjwF5TCme/uU1tzXs+LsLS8WXZvuMUejFOrUFEUKyzRvHJW5lskV/DhiMsTwJ/MEtGtjRVuWnAEcHxq/3ALsc3HfSi/qAqAiGlz3OpIKf3Hai6iiD37eJwHNd9QdJy4D32DJwY4Gw21ku7TO3FiLdtBT+Xdr3At8sWbbihFwErKrutT/FAVQKffUzCjHdEm9//W/shHufxYdnEh0m8cYp5Z5xK2bfnfhaKPB0rUZrrcw8T7LlvZKGogg==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-A79845F15C5549CA0514761283545482"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STR-A79845F15C5549CA0514761283545513"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-A79845F15C5549CA0514761283545351" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header><soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-A79845F15C5549CA0514761283545594"><Trzba xmlns="http://fs.mfcr.cz/eet/schema/v3"><Hlavicka dat_odesl="2016-08-19T19:06:37+02:00" prvni_zaslani="false" uuid_zpravy="2da635a5-d712-459d-9674-c12f335c39f7"/><Data celk_trzba="34113.00" cerp_zuct="679.00" cest_sluz="5460.00" dan1="-172.39" dan2="-530.73" dan3="975.65" dat_trzby="2016-08-05T00:30:12+02:00" dic_popl="CZ00000019" dic_poverujiciho="CZ683555118" id_pokl="/5546/RO24" id_provoz="273" porad_cis="0/6460/ZQ42" pouzit_zboz1="784.00" pouzit_zboz2="967.00" pouzit_zboz3="189.00" rezim="0" urceno_cerp_zuct="324.00" zakl_dan1="-820.92" zakl_dan2="-3538.20" zakl_dan3="9756.46" zakl_nepodl_dph="3036.00"/><KontrolniKody><pkp cipher="RSA2048" digest="SHA256" encoding="base64">a0asEiJhFCBlVtptSspKvEZhcrvnzF7SQ55C4DhnStnSu1b37GUI2+Dlme9P94UCPZ1oCUPJdsYOBZ3IX6aEgEe0FJKXYX0kXraYCJKIo3g64wRchE7iblIOBCK1uHh8qqHA66Isnhb6hqBOOdlt2aWO/0jCzlfeQr0axpPF1mohMnP3h3ICaxZh0dnMdju5OmMrq+91PL5T9KkR7bfGHqAoWJ0kmxY/mZumtRfGil2/xf7I5pdVeYXPgDO/Tojzm6J95n68fPDOXTDrTzKYmqDjpg3kmWepLNQKFXRmkQrkBLToJWG1LDUDm3UTTmPWzq4c0XnGcXJDZglxfolGpA==</pkp><bkp digest="SHA1" encoding="base16">9356D566-A3E48838-FB403790-D201244E-95DCBD92</bkp></KontrolniKody></Trzba></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What path in XML follows this `$doc->C14N`? Specifically what part of XML do you need to pass into `hash()`?

Comment: soap:Body, at least they say so. I have extracted that part of XML source above, but it is giving me other hash result than their example above.

Comment: `soap:Body` is the root. What is specific node in document you need to extract? The thing is, I have a method for you to use which does return hash values but differ by certain node texts. In fact in your link the `ds:DigestValue` exactly matches the hash you need without PHP function.

Comment: Thanks for yor response. Forgive me, I am not an XML guru so I am not sure I express myself clearly. This whole thing should serve to send values of the merchant bills. The important part is <Trzba> element, which contains all important values of the transaction, including VAT valuet etc and all signed with openssl (I have already accomplished this). However when I change any value in the example, the remote server returns soap signature error. This should be some standard way of hashing the XML document. The manual says:

Comment: "There has to be only one element soap:body included in the signature of the SOAP message including XML structure of the e-bill (eet:Trzba) assembled according to valid XML Schema (XSD). E-signature has to be realized according to XML Signature Syntax and Processing (Second Edition) with following requirements: and so on, including that digest of the soap:body has to be signed using SHA256."
I believe this is just some stupid thing due to my lack of knowledge of XML signing process. Therefore, from the example given, I am desperately trying to generate the correct SHA256 "hash" signature.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am having exact same problem!

Comment: I just remove exclusive and it worked, ex: echo base64_encode(hash('SHA1',$doc->C14N(),true));